# how to guard your params in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

in asp.net mvc, actiondispatcher will turn params into a model in an action, this process is called model binding, how do you call this in rails ? mass assignment in rails 3, strong parameters in rails 4 ?

and if i have a form with many input fields, the values formated as 100,000.00, when i submit the form, i need to reserve format all the values and then validate form, how to format it in models for insurance purposes ？

Updated:

```
 # find all numeric attributes and define a write_attribute method
 all_numeric_columns = Deal.columns.select {|x| [:float, :integer, :decimal].include?(x.type)}.map(&:name)
 all_numeric_columns.each do |column|
   class_eval <<-METHOD, __FILE__, __LINE__ + 1
     def #{column}=(the_value)
      write_attribute(:#{column}, the_value.gsub(',', ''))
     end
   METHOD
 end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mass assignment is correct. You would create or update a model by passing `params[:your_models_name]` to `YourModel.new` or `YourModel.find(params[:id]).update_attributes params[:your_model]`. Strong parameters is a way to whitelist the params that can be mass assigned.

[From the guides:](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/StrongParameters.html)

```
class PeopleController < ActionController::Base
  # Using "Person.create(params[:person])" would raise an
  # ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributes exception because it'd
  # be using mass assignment without an explicit permit step.
  # This is the recommended form:
  def create
    Person.create(person_params)
  end

  # This will pass with flying colors as long as there's a person key in the
  # parameters, otherwise it'll raise an ActionController::MissingParameter
  # exception, which will get caught by ActionController::Base and turned
  # into a 400 Bad Request reply.
  def update
    redirect_to current_account.people.find(params[:id]).tap { |person|
      person.update!(person_params)
    }
  end

  private
    # Using a private method to encapsulate the permissible parameters is
    # just a good pattern since you'll be able to reuse the same permit
    # list between create and update. Also, you can specialize this method
    # with per-user checking of permissible attributes.
    def person_params
      params.require(:person).permit(:name, :age)
    end
end
```

In the above example if the params that came in looked like this:

```
{ 
  person: {
    name: 'bob',
    age: 30,
    admin: true
  } 
}
```

Then the `admin: true` param would not have been assigned to bob's Person.

As for your input field format question, they should come in however they were on the form. Is this not the case for you?

Comment: thanks, this is for whitelist attributes, but it's not perfect for reformatting all numeric attributes, it's better to define some write_attribute methods, see updated answer.